# Code igniter-How to pass the indexed array from controller to view without making the indexed array to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm using this :

```
$users = $this->user_model->get_all_users();
```

Here `$users` is an indexed array.

Currently I am doing like following by making it to associative array and the passing to view so that we can use access that with the variable named with the key.

```
$data = array('json_users' => $users);

$this->load->view('view_all_users',$data);
```

how to do this without making the indexed array to associative array ?

Comment: directly pass the `$users` to the view., but it will rewrite other data you only get 1 result. You can't do it without renaming the other with different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, that's the only way to do it.

Comment: To whoever downvoted me - "there's no other way" is not a bad answer if that's true. And if it wasn't true, you'd be able to give a different answer which obviously is not the case.