# Passing Array from Controller to View Using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I am trying to pass an array with keys numbered 0 through 9 to my view. However, when I try to echo a specific key or a foreach for all keys to display the data, nothing shows.

My controller:

```
    $i=0;
    $cleanarray = array();

    foreach ($phrase as $innerphrase) {
        if (is_array($innerphrase)) {
            foreach ($innerphrase as $value) {
                $cleanarray[$i] = $value;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('blogview', $cleanarray);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => On Friday evenings in Thailand, sandwiched between the evening news and a popular soap opera, is a prime-time programme that has been running for three years, or ever since the military took power in a May 22, 2014 coup. 
    [1] => The Reds pulled off their biggest comeback in a year to finally end their pesky losing streak.
    [2] => A co-founder of Twitter says he's sorry if the popular social media platform helped put Donald Trump in the White House, as the president has suggested.
    [3] => Daniel Suarez is thrilled to be competing in the NASCAR All-Star race after struggling in his rookie season.
    [4] => Lexi Thompson remained in position for her first victory since a rules infraction cost her a major title, shooting a 2-under 69 in tricky wind conditions Saturday to take a three-stroke lead over In Gee Chun into the final round of the Kingsmill Championship.
    [5] => Boston Celtics guard Isaiah Thomas will miss the remainder of the NBA playoffs after aggravating a hip injury during Game Two of the Eastern Conference final, the team announced on Saturday.
    [6] => Yankees manager Joe Girardi has been ejected during an animated argument and New York pitching coach Larry Rothschild and Tampa Bay starter Matt Andriese also have been tossed in a testy game at Tropicana Field.
    [7] => Ed Carpenter turned a tough draw into a winning hand Saturday.
    [8] => Cloud Computing pulled off a major surprise in the Preakness Stakes in Maryland on Saturday, charging down the stretch to overtake Classic Empire and win the second race of U.S. thoroughbred racing's Triple Crown.
    [9] => Sometimes it pays to have a fresh horse.
)
```

My view:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>I am terrible at PHP!</h1>

        <h2><?php echo $0; ?></h2>  

</body>
</html>
```

However nothing shows. I have also tried using print_r in the same fashion. I am aware that CodeIgniter does not allow me to pass the variables in the controller and instead it allows me access directly to the keys in the array.

Ultimately I would like to iterate through the array and display all results but I'm trying to start "small" and at least get a single element of the array to pass through to the view. If someone could explain why this isn't working and then what one would do to use a for or foreach to iterate through the array, I would be very grateful.

I am aware that this question has likely been answered many times but for the life of me I cannot extrapolate the responses to these questions into a solution that works in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

**controller**:

```
$i=0;
$cleanarray = array();

foreach ($phrase as $innerphrase) {
    if (is_array($innerphrase)) {
        foreach ($innerphrase as $value) {
            $cleanarray[$i] = $value;
            $i++;
        }
    }
}

$array2 =  array();  // create a new array
$array2['contents']= $cleanarray; // add $cleanarray to the new array
$this->load->view('blogview', $array2); // pass the new array as the parameter
```

**Inside view file**:

echo ( "Contents: ");

// print the elements in $cleanarray

foreach ($contents as $val)

```
echo "$val<br/>";
```

**Note**: We can't access $array2 here. Instead, use '$contents[]'.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge codeigniter doesn't pass data without arrays from controller to view so you can try the below code i must sure that it works.

In your controller

```
    $i=0;
    $cleanarray = array();
    foreach ($phrase as $innerphrase) 
    {
         if (is_array($innerphrase)) 
         {
                foreach ($innerphrase as $value) 
                {
                        $cleanarray[$i] = $value;
                        $i++;
                }
         }
    }
    $data['cleanarray'] = $cleanarray
    $this->load->view('blogview', $data);
```

In your view print the array like this `print_r($cleanarray);` i am sure that this code will works.

Answer (score 1):

When passing your data from the controller to the view in a Codeigniter application, the second parameter of the `$this->load->view()` method call should be an associative array.

Within the view file, all of the first level keys in that payload are converted to variable names.  This is the behavior that you would expect from calling PHP's native `extract()` function on your controller array.

Your code can be adjusted this way:

Controller:

```
$payload = [];
foreach ($phrase as $innerPhrase) {
    if (is_array($innerPhrase)) {
        foreach ($innerPhrase as $payload['cleanArray'][]);
    }
}

$this->load->view('blogview', $payload);
```

View:

```
...
<?php
foreach ($cleanArray as $string) {
    echo "<h2>$string</h2>";
}
```

Relevant reading regarding the use of `extract()` on an indexed array: [Using php extract function with numeric indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52393650/2943403)

Long-time Codeigniter maintainer @Narf [just says no](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19426092/2943403).

Answer (score 1):

After creating $cleanarray in your controller apply this

```
$data['cleanarray'] = $cleanarray;//assign $cleanarray to $data
$this->load->view('blogview', $data);//pass $data to your view
```

And in the view to access your array apply this

```
<h2><?php echo $cleanarray[0]; ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my advice:

I don't recommend you to use number as variable name. To solve this, you can make its name started with '_'. Ex: `$_1`.

So in your looping change `$cleanarray[$i] = $value;` into `$cleanarray['_'.$i] = $value;`.

Of course you need to call it on view `echo $_0;`