# Using php extract function with numeric indexes

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert array values into variables using extract function. As extract function uses array keys as variable names and values as variable values.
I have an array with numeric keys as shown:

```
$my_array = array(0 =>"Cat", 1=>"Dog", 2=>"Horse");
extract($my_array);
```

How i would use numeric keys here as variable names to access values? Or `extract()` just deal with string keys?

Comment: You can do array_flip to change values to keys and then extract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the manual,

> You must use an associative array; a numerically indexed array will not produce results unless you use `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` or `EXTR_PREFIX_INVALID`.

You can add a prefix to your `extract()` function. This would, in the example below, add the `var_` prefix to each instance. You can supply whatever valid variable-prefix as the third argument - the created variables would reflect that parameter in the `extract()` function.

```
$my_array = array(0 =>"Cat", 1=>"Dog", 2=>"Horse");
extract($my_array, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "var");
```

The results can now be found in `$var_0` through `$var_2`.

- [Documentation](http://php.net/extract)
- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/jSNiW)

Comment: can you please see what if key value is changing every time for one particular array element. e.g. 0 =>"Cat" could be 3 =>"Cat" next time. It is a case with my project, so what I tried to do is find the key value first using `array_keys` function. stored the key value in some variable and tried to use it like this. `$key =(array_keys($Lng));print_r ($key);echo $key2 = $key[0];extract($Lng, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "var");echo $var_$key2;`.                                                                                            It does not work.

Comment: So you are looking for a way to find the key of a given value? `$key = array_search("Cat", $my_array);`

Comment: See this is the response of an array called $Lang = `Array ( [3] => GPS Longitude : 1 deg 26' 19.20" )` This array is already being extracted from some other array.  So in this case the key value is gonna change every time. so i thought of using array_keys function to fetch key first which returns me `Array ( [0] => 3 )`. I store this key into variables e.g. $key. Now i want to make it as `var_$key`  instead of `var_3` but it does not work. And I can not hardcode the key value.

Comment: can you help with that?

Comment: Sounds like you need the usage of *variable variables*. Although that is usually a sign that the structure of the program is poor, and that it should be approached differently. However, it will work. You need `echo ${"var_".$key2};`.

Comment: (Wouldn't stray too far with the answer. OP is trying to solve the wrong problem there/again.)