# How to get array values data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need small doubt in PHP. how to get below PHP array data in to variables.

```
$arraydata = Array
(
    [366] => 1084569.5892969
    [181TO365] => -2128157.619635
    [121TO180] => -59235.780429687
    [91TO120] => -266089.29
    [61TO90] => -56390
    [0TO60] => 8212872.9800098
)
```

This is my array output data.i need to get these data in to as variables like below.

$366data= 1084569.5892969;

$181TO365data = -2128157.619635;

$121TO180data = -59235.780429687;

$91TO120data = -266089.29;

$61TO90data = -56390;

$0TO60data = 8212872.9800098;
Like this variables get data . Can anyone help

Comment: [PHP variables cannot start with numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using php extract function with numeric indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393650/using-php-extract-function-with-numeric-indexes)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that PHP variables cannot start with a number (_ or letter) you can just loop over it like so:

```php
<?php

foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
  $$key = $value;
}
```

The $$ before key means that you assign the value of $key to a variable with that name. But you probably to prefix it with an _ to make this work.

For example:

```php
<?php

foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
  $prefixed = '_' . $key;
  $$prefixed = $value;
}
```

Why do you want this by the way?

Comment: From this code how can I take each variable separately.