# PHP - Making loop inside list()

Tags: php, web

Is there any way to create a loop of variables inside `list()`
I've tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
$long_string = "one , two , three , four";
$list = explode(" , ",$long_string);
$count_list = count($list);

list(for($i = 0; $i <= $count_list; $i++){ return ${"list$i"}; }) = explode(" , ",$long_string);
```

**Update : Got the solution, thanks**

Comment: Can you tell us your expected result because it's impossible to loop inside a list

Comment: `$list[0]`, `$list[1]` etc already has what you need.

Comment: @Youssef I trying to explode the string and set the variable for them but not fixing the amount of array. As normal in order to use `list()` it must be `list($variable1, $variable2, $variable3, $variable4) = explode(" , ",$long_string);` right? but in this case I trying to create a loop for the variable instead

Comment: Variable variables is a symptom that you should be declaring an array structure, but you are deliberately limiting the tools that you can use by avoiding an array structure.  I'm calling this question an XY Problem.

Comment: This'll get you very close: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52393728/2943403 https://3v4l.org/9Xbc5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use a while to produce the vars:

**php < 7.2** :

```
<?php
$long_string = "one , two , three , four";
$list = explode(" , ",$long_string);
while (list($key, $val) = each($list)) {
    ${"list".$key} = $val;
}
print_r($list0); //returns one
print_r($list1); //returns two
```

**PHP > 7.2: Alternate way**

```
    <?php
     $long_string = "one , two , three , four";
     $list = explode(" , ",$long_string);
     foreach($list as $key => $val) ${"list".$key} = $val;
     echo $list0;
     echo $list1;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to use `list()` for this. You're also returning from the loop in the first iteration, what doesn't make a lot of sense, and doing some redundant calculations. Additionally, you're creating one too many `$list` variables (0 to 4 are 5 variables for only 4 items).

All you need is:

```
foreach (explode(' , ', $long_string) as $k => $v) {
    ${"list$k"} = $v;
}
```

In any case, I have my concerns about the overall design. You already have a handy array thanks to `explode()`, and that feels more usable than independent variables popping up from nowhere which you can't easily list or enumerate.