# How to Show counted data to Html using php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

so here is my model codes:

```
public function GetId()
{
    $this->db->select('count(*) as total');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('dibaca', null);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

and this is my code in html:

```
<?= $DataId['total']; ?>
```

i already call the function to my controller as DataId,
and i get error that Undefined array key "total"

can you guys tell me what is wrong in it?

Comment: If you var_dump the $query->result_array(); what do you get?

Comment: an error that undefined array key "total"

Comment: No, I mean if you var dump the result of the getId function. That cant give that error, since you don't ask for that key there. I mean what does the data actually look like in the $DataId? Try var dumping $DataId without any keys in there.

Comment: We see your view and model code, but not your controller. Please show how you pass your data from the controller to the view.  `getId()` is a poor name for a method that returns a count.

Comment: @Hiro I believe this may be a misunderstanding between what `result_array()` returns and what `row_array()` returns.  Either try `row_array()` in the model, `$DataId[0]['total']` in the view, or clean up everything with the advice in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some untested advice:

Your model can be refined to:

```
public function countNullDibaca(): int
{
    return $this->db
        ->where("dibaca", null)
        ->count_all_results($this->table);
}
```

Your controller should call for the model data and pass it to the view.

```
public function myController(): void
{
    $this->load->model('my_model', 'MyModel');
    $this->load->view(
        'my_view',
        ['total' => $this->MyModel->countNullDibaca()]
    );
}
```

Finally, your view can access the variable that associates with the first-level key in the passed in array.

```
<?= $total; ?>
```

Here is [a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44340166/2943403) which speaks on passing data from the controller to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the result_array() at the model with

```
num_rows()
```

and you can delete ['total'] from your code in html, or like this:

```
<?= $DataId; ?>
```